# How to create a W3C-validation-link for local files?

Tags: html

I have some local (self generated) HTML files. I view them in browser via `file://` without a local webserver.

I would like to have a link in the footer of each of this files to "Validate" them on the W3C Validator. On some websites I see the links like this in source

```
<p class="validation"><a href="https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer">Validate</a></p>
```

But of course this doesn't work because there is no referer about local files.

I was [asking this on ProWebmaster](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/139064/100859) but the question was out of scope there.

**EDIT**: *File Upload* to the validator website via its web formular is not an option. I would like to send the whole HTML source to the validator without any external tools.

```
<a href="https://validator.w3.org/check?content={self.source}">Validate</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

The was the referer link works is to tell the validation service to look at the `Referer` header to get the URL to the previous page. Then to request that page and validate it.

Even if there was a `Referer` header for your local file, there is no way for the validation service to access it. It would be a serious security problem if every website you visited could read files from your hard disk freely!

Use the file upload feature to validate files without a public URL.

Alternatively, consider using a [local validation tool](https://html-validate.org/) and possibly looking for an extension to your IDE that makes it more convenient to access (such as [this extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=html-validate.vscode-html-validate)).